# Detect gestures on softkeyboard

Tags: flutter, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard, iphone-softkeyboard

Is there way to know when the keys are touched on softkeyboard (both onTap and onRelease timings)? If not is it possible to create my own keyboard that can do it using GestureDetector? What problems I might face if I go down that route?

This as for an flutter application where I wish to note user's typing style using touch timings.

Comment: have you seen https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RawKeyboardListener-class.html ?

Comment: Yes, but according to [https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22905](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22905) it does not work with softkeyboards. I only need the timings and it is ok if I don't get the particular character entered.